# Steganography decode is not giving me the right input key how do i fix it?

Tags: python, steganography

im not sure if the problem lies in the encode section or the decode i tried to fix it both ways nothing worked!

```
# Python program implementing Image Steganography

# PIL module is used to extract
# pixels of image and modify it
from PIL import Image

# Convert encoding data into 8-bit binary
# form using ASCII value of characters
def genData(data):

    # list of binary codes
    # of given data
    newd = []

    for i in data:
        newd.append(format(ord(i), '08b'))
    return newd

# Pixels are modified according to the
# 8-bit binary data and finally returned
def modPix(pix, data):

datalist = genData(data)
lendata = len(datalist)
imdata = iter(pix)

for i in range(lendata):

    # Extracting 3 pixels at a time
        pix = [value for value in imdata.__next__()[:3] +
                            imdata.__next__()[:3] +
                            imdata.__next__()[:3]]

    # Pixel value should be made
    # odd for 1 and even for 0
    for j in range(0, 8):
        if (datalist[i][j] == '0' and pix[j]% 2 != 0):
            pix[j] -= 1

        elif (datalist[i][j] == '1' and pix[j] % 2 == 0):
            if(pix[j] != 0):
                pix[j] -= 1
            else:
                pix[j] += 1
            # pix[j] -= 1

    # Eighth pixel of every set tells
    # whether to stop ot read further.
    # 0 means keep reading; 1 means thec
    # message is over.
    if (i == lendata - 1):
        if (pix[-1] % 2 == 0):
            if(pix[-1] != 0):
                pix[-1] -= 1
            else:
                pix[-1] += 1

    else:
        if (pix[-1] % 2 != 0):
            pix[-1] -= 1

    pix = tuple(pix)
    yield pix[0:3]
    yield pix[3:6]
    yield pix[6:9]

def encode_enc(newimg, data):
w = newimg.size[0]
(x, y) = (0, 0)

for pixel in modPix(newimg.getdata(), data):

    # Putting modified pixels in the new image
    newimg.putpixel((x, y), pixel)
    if (x == w - 1):
        x = 0
        y += 1
    else:
        x += 1
```

not sure if the problem lies here but i doubt it

```
# Encode data into image
def encode():
img = input("Enter image name(with extension) : ")
image = Image.open(img, 'r')

data = input("Enter data to be encoded : ")
if (len(data) == 0):
    raise ValueError('Data is empty')

newimg = image.copy()
encode_enc(newimg, data)

new_img_name = input("Enter the name of new image(with extension) : ")
newimg.save(new_img_name, str(new_img_name.split(".")[1].upper()))
```

here is where i think the problem is each time i try to decode the output is  "y" i tried to fix it but couldnt find a better solution

```
# Decode the data in the image
def decode():
img = input("Enter image name(with extension) : ")
image = Image.open(img, 'r')

data = ''
imgdata = iter(image.getdata())

while (True):
    pixels = [value for value in imgdata.__next__()[:3] +
                            imgdata.__next__()[:3] +
                            imgdata.__next__()[:3]]

    # string of binary data
    binstr = ''

    for i in pixels[:8]:
        if (i % 2 == 0):
            binstr += '0'
        else:
            binstr += '1'

    data += chr(int(binstr, 2))
    if (pixels[-1] % 2 != 0):
        return data
```

the main function works as it should i dont think i made a mistake here

```
# Main Function
def main():
a = int(input(":: Welcome to Steganography ::\n"
                    "1. Encode\n2. Decode\n"))
if (a == 1):
    encode()

elif (a == 2):
    print("Decoded Word : " + decode())
else:
    raise Exception("Enter correct input")

# Driver Code
if __name__ == '__main__' :

# Calling main function
main()
```

Comment: Lots of code, very little explanation. Check [\[SO\]: How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example (reprex (mcve))](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example).